# How often should I brush my animals?

Tags: story-of-seasons

I'm aware you need to brush them to prevent them from getting sick, but now that I am getting a pretty large amount of livestock and brushing them all takes a long time as well as big chunk of my stamina. Can I effectively skip a few days to just brush a few in batches and still prevent them from getting sick?

Comment: I suspect you can get away with it if you only brush them when they look dirty or it tells you they look mangy. You'll want to keep an eye on their stress levels in the log book. I wouldn't skip petting the animals daily (takes time, but not stamina). I also wouldn't get too many animals until you have dogs that can help you move them in and out of the barn for you.

Comment: Thanks for inspiring my [next question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/213872/when-can-i-get-a-dog)!

Comment: Just a tip: upgrade the brush. You brush much much faster, which also reduces stamina consumption.

Answer (score 1):

While brushing your animals everyday is not necessary, not brushing your animals raises Stress and causes them to get dirty, which isn't going to earn you points if you're aiming to enter them in the Livestock Festivals. When animals get too stressed, they stop producing and can get ill and die.

Now you can avoid the effects of Stress by talking to them, letting them outside to graze, and taking them to the Safari. Taking animals to the Safari costs 100G per head of livestock, but it reduces their Stress much more quickly than any other activity.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question if it's necessary to brush them daily. Sure never brushing them will eventually cause the problems you've mentioned, but that's not what he's suggesting.