# When can I get a dog?

Tags: story-of-seasons

Apparently dogs can help moving animals from barns to and from pastures. This is incredible. When can I get them? How many dogs would I need to handle all livestock? (like can 1 dog only handle 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a dog from the vendors starting Summer of the second year. You'll need to have built a pet house for them to live in. I'm not sure of the mechanics of how they work as I've heard conflicting accounts. I believe each dog, you can get multiple dogs, starts out herding one animal in and out of the barn each day. (Someone said the dog doesn't do this reliably at start, someone else said it was reliable. This may be because the time it happens is random and there's no cut-scene making it obvious it's happened.) As you increase the dog's heart level it should be able to herd more animals in and out of the barn.

Comment: yeesh. summer 2? that dog is going to be very busy by the time I can get it.

Comment: @Rapitor Well, even then it's going to take some time to get to the point where it can herd more than one animal a day. Dogs don't seem to be a useful in this game as others. I'd focus on quality over quantity with animals. Once you get an animal to max hearts you can be more lax with it.